# zf2 git vendor modules missing. how to include them into git repo?

Tags: git, zend-framework2

I'm pretty new to git and zf2. I just made a new new git repository on my server and pushed a zf2 app into it. however the vendor folder is not pushed nor the modules in it. How do i get git to push the vendor and modules folder?

I believe problem is because vendor modules are coming from git and have .git folders and .gitignore files within them. Tried removing .gitignore files from them, but this doesn't work out.

Comment: `php composer.phar install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you got it right on "I believe problem is because vendor modules are coming from git and have .git folders and `.gitignore` files within them." Could it be you missed some files when deleting?

There are submodules for:

```
vendor/
vendor/doctrine/common
vendor/doctrine/dbal
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module
vendor/doctrine/orm
```

if you are going to push all of the vendor then you can remove `.gitignore` and `.gitmodules` (if exists) from all of the above directory and edit `.gitignore` and delete `.gitmodules` from projectroot/  and then add whole of the vendor to the parent git again. It should work.